# Google sheets slider for a multi-valued cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have cells in Google sheets that have multiple values, such as:

| Continent | Law |
| --- | --- |
| North America | Sarbanes Oxley, Freedom of Information Act |
| Europe | Digital Markets Act, Digital Services Act |

By default, it groups the items like this in the slicer for the "Law" column:

1. Sarbanes Oxley, Freedom of Information Act
2. Digital Markets Act, Digital Services Act

I'd like to create a Google docs slicer with each item in the "Law" column individually, such as:

1. Sarbanes Oxley
2. Freedom of Information Act
3. Digital Markets Act
4. Digital Services Act

How do I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to do this with a slicer. But you should be able to split the text and create a new table with a formula.

```
ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(BYROW(B2:B3, LAMBDA(row, TRIM(SPLIT(row,","))))))
```

With B2:B3 being replaced with the cell reference for the "Law" Column.